# Airflow DAG does not run at specified time with catchup=False

Tags: airflow

I have an airflow DAG, for which it doesn't really make sense to backfill. I figured out that with airflow 1.8, you can give the DAG the parameter `catchup=False`, so it will only start the most recent job.
That said, I want to have the DAG start at midnight and run daily.
But. And that's the thing now: The DAG starts immediately and not at midnight. Also when I clear all DAG runs, it will start immediately again. The DAG will then run daily, but will be scheduled at the wrong time it started + 1 day.

How can I have a DAG which only starts running the most recent job, **and** starts at a specific time (midnight)?

Here is the code I use:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

default_args = {'depends_on_past': False,
                'start_date': datetime(2013, 1, 1)}

with DAG('test_dag',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:
    test = DummyOperator(task_id='test')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put crontab in schedule_interval, more detail can be found here: https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#dag-runs, for example `schedule_interval="0 0 * * *"`

Also, Airflow is running under UTC, please adjust your "midnight" to the correct timezone.

Comment: Thanks! I see, alright. So can I also put `schedule_interval = @daily` in there or do I always have to use crontab in there?

The UTC thing I still have to figure out. I still haven't found where to configure my timezone in airflow properly... But I guess it's enough to convert my timezone to UTC for now.

Comment: @jabberwocky, `@daily` is just an easy way to express "0 0 * * *", if you don't live in UTC, you need to specify what you mean by midnight under UTC, for example, US-EST, I can put "0 5 * * *" which is the midnight.

Comment: FYI there is a [pull request](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2781) being reviewed to add timezone support, so it may come soon.

Comment: Hey @Chengzhi, worked like a charm. Many thanks!

Also, I'll watch out for the PR. Seems like it's ready soon!